# Script for renaming files in a specific way

Tags: powershell, text, replace

Is there a possibility to build a script (PowerShell for instance) where the file will be renamed with specific text according to specific text?

I have thousands of files like:

- 12345_id_user.pdf
- 23456_id_user.pdf
- 34567_id_user.pdf
- 45678_id_user.pdf

  etc.

And I need to change first part (digits) with another specific id:

12345 → 98765

23456 → 87654

34567 → 76543

I have list (excel/notepad/word) of new ids and old ids that need to be replaced.

So, is it possible to create a script where it will look for name '12345' compare it to new list and change to '98765'?

Update 2:

```cs
$Path = "C:\Users\oledv\Desktop\TestEnv\"
$Text = $arrExcelValuesA
#$PathArray = @()
#$Results = "C:\temp\test.txt"

function Release-Ref ($ref) {
    ([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$ref) -gt 0)
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}
$arrExcelValuesA = @()

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objWorkbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\oledv\Desktop\TestEnv\TestIds.xlsx")
$objWorksheet = $objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.pdf" | ForEach-Object {
    $FileName = Get-Content $_.Name
    Write-Output $FileName
    $i = 1

    do {
        $arrExcelValuesA = $objWorksheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).Value()
        $i++
    } while ($FileName -eq $arrExcelValuesA)

    $row = $objWorkSheet.Cells.Find($arrExcelValuesA).row
    $col = $objWorkSheet.Cells.Find($arrExcelValuesA).column
    $NewName = $objWorksheet.Cells.Item($row, $col+1).Value()+$arrExcelValuesA.Substring(5)
    Rename-Item -Path $_.Name -NewName $NewName
}
```

It renames first file, but looks like it doesn't go through all files in folder...

```
Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At C:\Users\oledv\Desktop\TestEnv\Check.ps1:40 char:18
+                  Rename-Item -Path $_.Name -NewName $NewName
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\oledv\...456_id_user.pdf:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At C:\Users\oledv\Desktop\TestEnv\Check.ps1:40 char:18
+                  Rename-Item -Path $_.Name -NewName $NewName
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\oledv\...567_id_user.pdf:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At C:\Users\oledv\Desktop\TestEnv\Check.ps1:40 char:18
+                  Rename-Item -Path $_.Name -NewName $NewName
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\oledv\...678_id_user.pdf:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At C:\Users\oledv\Desktop\TestEnv\Check.ps1:40 char:18
+                  Rename-Item -Path $_.Name -NewName $NewName
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\oledv\...789_id_user.pdf:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At C:\Users\oledv\Desktop\TestEnv\Check.ps1:40 char:18
+                  Rename-Item -Path $_.Name -NewName $NewName
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\oledv\Desktop\TestEnv\xxxx.pdf:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Comment: You have a clear requirement and also a strategy to do it. Please also show some of the code you have already tried

Comment: You also need to decide upon your list format, out of those three I would suggest a plain text format, i.e. Notepad. Then you'll need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58130410/edit) to include an example of the content and layout of that file. Without that we cannot do anything but guess.

Comment: @Theo Sure, I have stopped there...

Comment: @Compo I decided to try excel

Comment: It would make things a lot easier if you create a CSV file from that Excel and let it have two columns, the first being the values to find, the second having the values to replace them with (your code seems to read only one column from the Excel file). Armed with that, you can simply get the files in the directory that match the value to find using the `-Filter` parameter and rename them using the value from the second column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, it would be a lot simpler if you put the old and new ID values in a CSV file like this:

```
"OldID","NewID"
"12345","98765"
"23456","87654"
"34567","76543"
```

Then, something like below should work:

```
# read this CSV to get an array of PSObjects
$ids = Import-CSV -Path 'D:\ReplaceId.csv'

# build a lookup table from the $ids variable
$hash = @{}
$ids | ForEach-Object { $hash[$_.OldID] = $_.NewID }

# next, get a list of all files that have names starting with any 
# of the 5 digits from column 'OldID' and loop through
Get-ChildItem -Path 'THE PATH TO YOUR DIRECTORY' -Filter '*.pdf' -File | 
    Where-Object { $hash.Keys -contains $_.Name.Substring(0,5) } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        # get the value for the new ID from the lookup hashtable
        # and combine it with the remainder of the filename
        $newName = '{0}{1}' -f $hash[$($_.Name.Substring(0,5))], $_.Name.Substring(5)
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName -WhatIf
    }
```

If the console info shows the correct replacement names, remove the `-WhatIf` switch to actually start renaming the files

If you add the `-Recurse` switch to the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet, the code will also rename files inside any subfolder.

---

**Update**

---

Of course, the above assumes there is **no mix** of Old and New Id numbers in the folder. Since you commented that this is the case you will get *file already exists* errors.
To overcome that, you need to make sure the new filenames are unique inside the folder. You can do that for instance like this.

It appends an index number between brackets to the name if a file with that name already exists.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.pdf' -File | 
    Where-Object { $hash.Keys -contains $_.Name.Substring(0,5) } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        # get the value for the new ID from the lookup hashtable
        # and combine it with the remainder of the filename
        $newId = $hash[$($_.Name.Substring(0,5))]
        $newName = '{0}{1}' -f $newId, $_.Name.Substring(5)
        # since a filename with the new ID may already exist, 
        # you need to create a unique filename by appending an indexnumber
        $fullName = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath $newName
        $index = 1
        while (Test-Path -Path $fullName -PathType Leaf) {
            $newName = '{0}{1}({2}){3}' -f $newId, $_.BaseName.Substring(5), $index++, $_.Extension
            $fullName = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath $newName
        }
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName -WhatIf
    }
```

**Before:**

> ```
> D:\TEST
>     12345_id_user.pdf
>     12345_id_user2.pdf
>     12345_id_user3.pdf
>     23456_id_user.pdf
>     34567_id_user.pdf
>     34567_id_user2.pdf
>     76543_id_user2.pdf
>     98765_id_user.pdf
> ```

**After:**

> ```
> D:\TEST
>     76543_id_user.pdf
>     76543_id_user2(1).pdf
>     76543_id_user2.pdf
>     87654_id_user.pdf
>     98765_id_user(1).pdf
>     98765_id_user.pdf
>     98765_id_user2.pdf
>     98765_id_user3.pdf
> ```

**Or** if you want to increase the index number you already seem to apply, use this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.pdf' -File | 
    Where-Object { $hash.Keys -contains $_.Name.Substring(0,5) } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        # get the value for the new ID from the lookup hashtable
        # and combine it with the remainder of the filename
        $newId    = $hash[$($_.Name.Substring(0,5))]
        $newName  = '{0}{1}' -f $newId, $_.Name.Substring(5)
        # since a filename with the new ID may already exist, 
        # you need to create a unique filename by incrementing the indexnumber

        # get the basename of the new name without any index numbers at the end
        $baseName  = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($newName) -replace '\d+$'
        $extension = $_.Extension
        # get an array of all file and folder names of items with a similar name already present in the folder
        $similar = @(Get-ChildItem $_.DirectoryName -Filter "$baseName*$extension" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
        $index = 1
        while ($similar -contains $newName) {
            $newName = '{0}{1}{2}' -f $baseName, $index++, $extension
        }

        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName -WhatIf
    }
```

**Before:**

> ```
> D:\TEST
>     12345_id_user.pdf
>     12345_id_user2.pdf
>     12345_id_user3.pdf
>     23456_id_user.pdf
>     34567_id_user.pdf
>     34567_id_user2.pdf
>     76543_id_user2.pdf
>     98765_id_user.pdf
> ```

**After:**

> ```
> D:\TEST
>     76543_id_user.pdf
>     76543_id_user1.pdf
>     76543_id_user2.pdf
>     87654_id_user.pdf
>     98765_id_user.pdf
>     98765_id_user1.pdf
>     98765_id_user2.pdf
>     98765_id_user3.pdf
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for comment. I will try this option as well. However I managed to rename first file using this code, but it looks like it doesn't go through all files in folder. I will add as UPD2

Comment: The thing is that the file can repeat several times with the same id like 12345_id_user.pdf / 12345_id_user2.pdf / 12345_id_user3.pdf and 12345 still needs to be changed with 98765

Comment: @Oleg_D You apparently have a mix of old and new ID numbered files in the folder which wasn't clear in the question. I have added new code to _uniqify_ the new filenames.

Comment: Yes! You are right .cvs way is much convenient and clear... Now I got it :) Thank you very much for your help and time!

Comment: @Oleg_D In that case I think it would be easier to do `$newId = ($_.Name -split '_')[0]` or using a regex like `$newId = ([regex] '^([^_]+)').Matches($_.Name).Groups[1].Value` or `$newId = ([regex] '^(\d+)(?=_)').Matches($_.Name).Groups[1].Value`